# Why doesn't this SQL run? Firebird stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, firebird, firebird2.5

I execute the following simple query in `IBExpert` [firebird2.5](/questions/tagged/firebird2.5) and it works fine:

```
SELECT
   pd.NOME_PRODUTO,
   es.QTDE_MINIMA
FROM
   TBL_ESTOQUE es,
   TBL_PRODUTO pd
WHERE
   es.qtde_estoque = 0
   AND es.produto = pd.id
ORDER BY
   pd.NOME_PRODUTO
```

But, if I create a stored procedure with two output parameters (see below)

```
begin
SELECT
  pd.NOME_PRODUTO,
  es.QTDE_MINIMA
FROM
  TBL_ESTOQUE es,
  TBL_PRODUTO pd
WHERE
  es.qtde_estoque = 0
  AND es.produto = pd.id
ORDER BY
  pd.NOME_PRODUTO
into :nome_produto, :qtde_minima;
suspend;
end
```

I get a message like this:

> multiple rows in singleton select. multiple rows in singleton
>   select. At proceddure 'SPD_SALDO_PROD_ZERADO_ESTOQUE' line: 7, col:3"

What is this? I don't understand what is happening...

Comment: Well the error message is pretty clear isn't it? How many rows does your select return?

Answer (score 3):

```
FOR SELECT ...
INTO ...
DO SUSPEND;
```

Answer (score 3):

rstrelba's answer shows how to fix the problem.  If you want to understand it, here's what's going on.

`suspend` inside a Firebird stored procedure returns a row to the caller.  It can be used in various different ways, and can be thought of as similar to Python's `yield` statement: suspend operation and send back a single value (or row, in this case), then continue when the caller asks for more data.  (It has to be done this way for technical reasons, because database drivers don't always pull the entire result set all at once.)

You've got a `select` query that can return an arbitrary number of values, followed by a single `suspend`.  Firebird is erroring out, telling you that this is probably wrong.  What you want to do is put the select in a for loop, which will loop over the result set and suspend once for each row, as rstrelba's answer demonstrates.  This makes sure that the caller gets all the results back.

Comment: I'm afraid that you are a slightly wrong. I think that the problem is not in the `suspend`. But in the `into` part.